# Entity to Json do not map all field

Tags: java, json, rest

When I try to send my entity with a JsonFormat (website to restful). My restful does not have the field of date, but this field is not @XmlTransient so I do not why ? I give you Log :

```
HTTP RESPONSE : Header: {Content-Type=[application/json]} - Entity: [EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@4ff2e717, EJPlanning.Models.Utilisateur@37c1ff47]
HTTP REQUEST : User: unknown - Path: /disponibilite/4801 - Header: {accept=[application/json], content-type=[application/json], user-agent=[Jersey/2.10.4 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)], host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive], content-length=[11]} - Entity: {"id":4816}
```

**Disponibilite Class**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Disponibilite implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    private String dateToString;


    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @NotNull
    private Collection<Utilisateur> utilisateurs;


    public Disponibilite() {
    }

    public Disponibilite(int id, String dateToString, Date date, Collection<Utilisateur> utilisateurs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dateToString = dateToString;
        this.date = date;
        this.utilisateurs = utilisateurs;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.id = Id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String dateEvenementString) {
        Date date2 = null;
        try{
        date2 = format.parse(dateEvenementString);
        }catch(ParseException e){
            try {
                date2 = sdf.parse(dateEvenementString);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
            }
        }
        this.date  = date2;    
    }



    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Utilisateur> getUtilisateurs() {
        return utilisateurs;
    }

    public void setUtilisateurs(Collection<Utilisateur> Utilisateurs) {
        this.utilisateurs = Utilisateurs;
    }

    public void addUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur){
        Boolean estDejaDansLaListe = false;
        for(Utilisateur utilisateurfor : utilisateurs){
            if(utilisateurfor.getId() == utilisateur.getId()){
            estDejaDansLaListe= true;
            }       
        }
        if(estDejaDansLaListe){
        SessionBeanEFPlanning.displayFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cet Utilisateur est déjà sélectionné  !");    
        }else{
        this.utilisateurs.add(utilisateur);
        }
    }

    public void removeUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur){
        this.utilisateurs.remove(utilisateur);
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getDateToString() {
        this.dateToString=sdf.format(date.getTime());
        return dateToString;
    }

    public void setDateToString(String dateToString) {
        this.dateToString = dateToString;
        setDate(dateToString);
    }
```

About Transient field It is because I do not need that. I have already seen if date was not null or if an error occured but nothing

Comment: Try adding an annotation that also parses the  null values, Are you sure that your class variables are initialized properly and are not null?

Comment: I solved by adding @XmlElement thank for your reply